# No provider for ConnectionBackend - (angular2 and springBoot)

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, angular2-services

i'm trying to connect my spring boot project as my back-end using angular 2 as front-end.
based on web-service my back-end provide an API which present on JSON, then from here i'm building my front-end then 'm try to consume Restful service.
eventually, no component in running, a blank page displayed with three error on my web browser said:

> error 1:

```
ERROR Error: No provider for ConnectionBackend!
at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9475)
at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.es5.js:10557)
at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11060)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10916)
```

> error 2:

```
AppComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR CONTEXT  DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}
```

> error 3:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ConnectionBackend! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for ConnectionBackend!
at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9475)
at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.es5.js:10557)
at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11060)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10916) Error: No provider for ConnectionBackend!
at injectionError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:33285:90)
at noProviderError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:33323:12)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:34765:19)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:34804:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:34736:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:34605:21)
at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:41591:25)
at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:42673:16)
at resolveDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43176:45)
at createClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43032:35)
```

anyway guessing my back-end just gonna give as only one list in the other hand the angular2 project just gonna list all att names from the list provided by spring boot.
here my Angular code:
`app.component.ts`

```
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>Consumming a restful Webservice using angular 2</h1>
  <ul>
    <li #ngFor="item of personsLst">
      {{item.id}}
    </li>
  </ul>`,
  providers: [Http]
})
export class AppComponent {
   personsLst: Array<string> = [];
  theDataSource: Observable<string>;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.theDataSource = this.http.get('/persons/dolist')
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
 ngOnInit() {
    // get the data from the rest service
    this.theDataSource.subscribe(
      data => {
      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        this.personsLst = data;
      }else {
      this.personsLst.push(data);
      }
      },
      err =>
        console.log('can not get the persons list. Error code: %s, URL: %s', err.status, err.url),
      () => console.log('Person(s) retrieved')
    );
  }
}
```

Note: i'm using the angular command line interface in this project!!

Comment: Are you importing HttpModule in your module file?

Comment: problem's fixed thanks